# SSO siteminder configurations to work on IIS7 integrated mode with MVC4 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, single-sign-on, siteminder, integrated-pipeline-mode

I am working on a MVC4 application on IIS7 Windows 2008 R2 server and trying to integrate SSO siteminder with my application. However I am not able to find exact documentaiton around how to do so. I am looking for configeration settings for both server and web.config of my application. I am running my application in integrated mode. Siteminder is already configured on server, i need server settings just to verify.

I can see CASiteMinderWebAgentHandler and CASiteMinderWebAgentHandler-32 in modules on applicationHost.config on server.

I am not sure what to put in web.config of my app to make it work.

Please let me know in case you need any other information. I have been searching about it for couple of days now but nowhere I have found exact doucmentation. Please help. Any help will be highly appreciated.